# Are answers being deleted too easily?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

In the question
[Is there another destination like Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/is-there-another-destination-like-thailand),  I came across [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9689/583), which I upvoted, only to notice shortly afterwards that **it had been deleted**.

[image]

This was [jeffmcneill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3222/jeffmcneill)'s first answer on this site, and I think it's a good, high-quality one, even if it's mainly pointing out it's hard to find "another Thailand". (Also note that jeffmcneill probably knows what he's talking about, as he lives in Thailand.)

No comment or anything, just straight delete. I don't think such a sober post by a new user should *ever* be met quite like that, even if it was somewhat off-topic or non-optimal. (Which this answer isn't, IMHO.)

A vote to undelete it cannot be cast, since:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

I think, at least in this case, Mark was being too trigger-happy with his delete privileges. Any opinions?

## Update

Sorry, I failed to notice **the answer was converted to a comment** on the question.
So I guess my point now is:

- IMHO it was a valid answer to begin with. -> **Are answers being converted to comments too easily?**
- That particular answer is **too long** to fit in a comment, and it currently gets cut off mid-sentence (see screenshot below). Also, in general, converting to a comment hampers the readability of a post to some extent, as it loses formatting into paragraphs, etc.

[image]

Comment: Note that the answer was converted to a comment as part of the deletion—and I agree with Mark's decision, since the answer isn't an answer to the question as posed. It's probably helpful to the OP, but since it doesn't answer the question, it belongs in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation whether jeffmcneill's post "answered the question as posed". Reading all of it carefully, I think it does. (It's completely ok if an answer points out problems with assumptions made in the question, etc.)

Comment: The question asked about OTHER countries. He failed to mention another country.  It's ok to point out problems, but that is what *comments* are for.

Comment: @Mark; he DID mention another country (namely Bali, Indonesia). It's in the part that got lost in conversion :P But whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would have kept the answer and left it to be upvoted / downvoted. Even though it does not mention other countries, it gives an explanation as to why it's unlikely to other countries. I see this as similar to the question: [Is there are an equivalent to Seat61 for bus travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-man-in-seat-sixty-one-for-bus-travel) where IMO, as I wrote in my answer, the best answer in this situation is there is none. So there can be questions where a good answer could be, "No, there's no alternative.

The other thing is that I think the 'convert to comment' should be used mostly in cases where the answer is one sentence or less and doesn't add much to the discussion. Without any intention of pointing fingers, I'd say [this answer on the same Thailand question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9609/108) is a better candidate to be turned into a comment (and even then it'd be a borderline decision for me, so I'd leave it alone). In this case it was a fairly well-fleshed out answer, so if at all it was 'wrong', then I'd have downvoted rather than delete it.

Just my two cents.

Comment: I agree on both counts. (Minor detail: jeffmcneill's answer **did** mention one other country (Bali, Indonesia); see the last sentence.)

Comment: Since most people seem to agree with @Ankur on this, how about resolving this particular case by undeleting [the answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9689/583) (and removing the comment it was partially converted to)?

Comment: Done this. Also deleted extraneous comments.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for keeping an eye on things Jonik, good to know there's people watching who care :) But I didn't delete it, I moved it to a comment.  Answers are for **answers**.  However there was still some interesting stuff in there, so rather than deleting it outright, it was moved to be a comment instead.  Good question to ask though, hope that addresses any queries you have.  Can always flag me in chat too if you're not sure about something one of us has done - we try to be open about it.

Comment: as an aside, it's always bugged me that it says "deleted" when we move.  Why not have the text say "this answer was moved to a comment" instead.  Ah well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was converted to a comment! (I *think* the comment wasn't there (yet) when I wrote my comment on the question, and subsequently wrote the meta question.)

Comment: A problem remains though: the answer is **too long** for a comment, and if you look closer, you'll see that the comment get's cut out mid-sentence!

Comment: It generally happens instantly, when we convert them.  Yeah, I'm not really sure what to do when it's too long....it'd be nice if we could split it into two or something :/

Comment: Seriously, someone downvoted an _explanation_?

Comment: @MarkMayo On meta downvotes work different as you should know ;) I think someone just didn't agree with your decision.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Whenever you find something like this in the system that irks you, I urge you to file a feature request on meta.SO - it's our system we should try to get it improved when we find the icky bits.